# Misuse of "behoove"?

Tags: word-usage

I've come across the following usage of "*behooves*" in a scientific paper (don't worry about the content).

*Deriving approximation guarantees for CLASH **behooves** us to assume the restricted isometry property (...).*

I always thought that "*behoove*" was equivalent to "*be necessary for*". For instance:

*It behooves us to take their words into account.*

In the example, however, "*behooves*" seems to mean "*forces*", as in

*Deriving approximation guarantees for CLASH **forces** us to assume the restricted isometry property.*

So, is the first example a proper usage of "*behooves*"?

Comment: I always thought 'behooves' means 'requires' or 'mandates' or 'strongly urges', which would therefore work equally well in both of your examples

Comment: @Marv I think the point is: Does deriving behoove, or is one simply behooved? I would vote that behooving is always passive, not active.  It is correct to say that because of circumstances, Sue is behooved.  It is incorrect to say that circumstances behoove Sue. I haven't taken the time to find references to support this view.

Comment: @jejorda2 That's exactly the point.

Comment: @jejorda2 Good point, you might be right...

Comment: Lessee -- "The glue factory behooved the horses."

Comment: The simple fix would be to add an "In" at the beginning of the sentence, and a comma and an "it" after "CLASH": "In deriving approximation guarantees for CLASH, it behooves us to assume the restricted isometry property ..."

Answer (score 2):

The word ***behove/behoove*** has had various meanings across the centuries as evidenced by the multiplicity of senses quoted in the OED.

The one which most clearly corresponds to the way I have heard it used, and the only one I noticed with examples as recent as the 20th century was sense 4a.

> 4a. with the thing incumbent expressed by an infinitive, and with
>   personal object: It is incumbent upon or necessary for (a person) to
>   do (something).

The sense has examples dating from circa 1200, but the two most recent are:

> 1952   M. McCarthy Groves of Academe (1953) iii. 40   It behooved him
>   to tread warily with Domna.
>
> 1955   Sci. Amer. Aug. 71/1   It behooves us to know as much as
>   possible about this problem.
>
> **Etymology**:  Old English bi- , behófian  (corresponding to Middle Low German behoven , Middle Dutch and Dutch behoeven ), < bihóf n.:
>   see behoof n.  Lit. ‘to be of behoof or use.’ Historically, it rhymes
>   with move, prove, but being now mainly a literary word, it is
>   generally made to rhyme with rove, grove, by those who know it only in
>   books. Compare prove, proof: behove, behoof. The spelling with -oo- is
>   now restricted to the United States.

Comment: Interesting. Does any of those meanings correspond to the example I mentioned? I agree with you that the definition you provided seems to be the most common one today. In fact, it's the only one I have ever heard or read, I think.

Comment: @broncoAbierto You really need to get into the OED and take a look at this. Some of the senses have no examples since the 17th century. )Ohers have 19th century uses. In the UK virtually anyone who pays council tax has access to the OED on-line, through their local library. Otherwise I'm afraid it is a subscription service..

Comment: Well, I pay my taxes elsewhere, so let's hope someone remembers I'm a word freak next Christmas... Thanks for the pointer, and for sharing those interesting facts on the pronunciation of "behoove".